# Core Data with to Many relationship - Creating a NSPredicate with ALL in SUBQUERY

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

My object graph looks like this

SnapShot -->> Pane --> ManagedImage

I'm trying to find a SnapShot that has the exact ManagedImages contained with in a set.

The code I've got now returns an Array of SnapShots that have one or more of the ManagedImages that are in the set. I then search through the Array to find the correct SnapShot but I'm guessing it would be much faster to filter in the Subquery

With an NSPredicate how can I get the unique SnapShot that has ALL of the ManagedImages that are in the set?

Here's my code

```
mySet = ... // A unique set of (usually 3) managedImages that I'm trying to find a snapShot for

NSFetchRequest *request = ...
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SnapShot" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

// Want this to work but sends an exception
//request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(self.panes, $pane, ALL $pane.managedImage IN %@).@count != 0", mySet];

// Using this
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(self.panes, $pane, $pane.managedImage IN %@).@count != 0", mySet];
```

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is that if you already have managed objects in hand, you don't fetch but instead walk the relationships from the managed objects you have to the managed objects you want.

So, your relationship graph probably actually looks like this:

```
SnapShot <-->> Pane <--> ManagedImage
```

or maybe:

```
SnapShot <<-->> Pane <<--> ManagedImage
```

Since you have a set of `ManagedImage` objects all you have to do is walk the keypath of `pane.snapShot` or `panes.snapShots` to find the `SnapShot` objects associated with each `ManagedImage` object. Then you just extract the unique `SnapShot` objects.

In the first case, the matter is trivial because of the one-to-one relationship path of

```
ManagedImage-->Pane-->SnapShot
```

In the second case, you will need to first get all the unique SnapShot objects:

```
NSSet *shots=[aMangedImageObj valueForKeyPath:@"distinctUnionOfSets.panes.snapShots"];
```

... for each `ManagedImage` instances and then merge all the sets with `setByAddingObjectsFromSet:` or a similar method to produce a single set of unique objects.

Fetches should be used to find the first objects in graph that you need but once you have the objects, you don't fetch but walk the relationships. Otherwise, there is not much point to having relationships in the first place.